# Limit to 1 word with exact length in Tesseract OCR

Tags: captcha, tesseract

I have scrapping project. The problem is it have captcha. I use Tesseract OCR to decode the captcha but I got low accuracy. I think if we give limit to the ocr engine, the accuracy will increase. The captcha contains just one word with exact length (6 digit number).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?